# nodejs child_process 'spawn()' in build version of electron not working

Tags: node.js, electron, child-process

I am running into a weird problem when I try to run my electron app in build version instead of dev. Below is a source code I think is relevant...

```
const isPythonExe = process.env.PYTHON_EXE === "true"; // env variable to select between exe or py 
const opencvModulePath = isPythonExe ? ["opencv", "dist", "main_prod", "main_prod.exe"] : ["opencv", "main.py"] // comment out before build
// const opencvModulePath = ["dist", "main_prod", "main_prod.exe"]; // -> comment in before build

let options = {
  scriptPath : path.join(app.getAppPath(), ...opencvModulePath),
  args : []
}
let python_cp;

const spawnPythonChildProcess = () => {
  console.log(`spawing python process on path ${options.scriptPath}`)
  return new Promise(function(resolve, _) {
    python_cp = isPythonExe ? spawn(options.scriptPath) : spawn("python", [options.scriptPath, [...options.args]]); // comment out before build
    // python_cp = spawn(options.scriptPath, {shell : true}) // comment in before build 
      function errorCallback(err) {
      console.log('failed to launch python_cp with error\n', err.toString());
      python_cp.stdout.removeListener('data', stdoutCallback)
      resolve(false);      
    }

    function stdoutCallback(res) {
      const {status} = JSON.parse(res.toString());
      if (status === 'successful') resolve(true)
      else resolve(false)
    }
    
    python_cp.stdout.once('data', function(res) {
      const {status} = JSON.parse(res.toString())
      if (status === 'successful') {
        resolve(true);
      }
    })

    //the process failed to start
    python_cp.on('error', errorCallback)

    //pipe the stderr to process.stderr
    python_cp.stderr.pipe(process.stderr)
    //pipe the stdout to process.stdout 
  })
}
```

When I run my electron app in dev mode and isPythonExe set to true, the `spawn(options.scriptPath)` successfully launches the executable. For testing purposes, I even start a TCP server on a different thread and using telnet client, I can see that indeed the executable started. My app runs as it is supposed to run in dev. However, after building my electron app, the same `spawn(options.scriptPath)` does not seem to launch the executable. because my app does not work and the telnet client fails to connect too. I even tried {shell : true} option for build version but to no avail.
To be more specific, I am using nextron for the app and packaging my electron app for win32 x64 arch. And using pyinstaller to compile my python modules into native executables. When I unpack the asar file, The main_prod.exe is in the correct path and spawn() never throws an error for a non-existent path.

Edit: I was able to figure out a temporary workaround after following https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/9459 . It has something to do with how asar deals the file paths but I am not sure. I was able to have a temporary workaround by setting

```
"build" : {
   "asar" : false
}
```

Can anyone explain why this issue happens and a workaround for this? I still cannot figure out